# How to implement MPI_Datatype starting from scratch? (In a new OS)

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to implement the MPI protocol in EPOS Operation System. 
In this moment, I am studying the MPI_Datatypes.
Well, I wrote a document with some mpi types, in this way:

`typedef unsigned int MPI_Datatype;`

`#define MPI_CHAR           ((MPI_Datatype)1)`

`#define MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR  ((MPI_Datatype)2)`

`#define MPI_BYTE           ((MPI_Datatype)3)`

`#define MPI_SHORT          ((MPI_Datatype)4)`

`#define MPI_UNSIGNED_SHORT ((MPI_Datatype)5)`

`.....`

But, I think it's not good!
How could I explicit write that the MPI_CHAR is equivalent to **1 byte character** (a char type in C language). Or, for example, MPI_INT is equivalent to **32-bit integer**. Are that possible? I would like some tips! Thanks a lot! (Sorry if the title of this topic is not so understandable!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `MPI_CHAR` is not equivalent to a char type: you cannot declare a variable of MPI_CHAR type. `MPI_CHAR` is just an integer constant that tells MPI to process the data as a sequence of `char`s.

So what you have done is quite correct.

You should then map each supported `MPI_Datatype` to a real type at the place(s) where the MPI implementation processes the MPI_Datatype values. E.g. in `MPI_Send` when determining amount of data to be sent.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like:
std::map <int, any_type> my_mapping; my_mapping[MPI_INT] = int; ???

Comment: Well, for each MPI_Datatype, you need to know size of variables of this type, and maybe also memory alignment rules (that depends on your target platform). So you can write something like `std::map <MPI_Datatype, size_t> datatype_sizes; datatype_sizes[MPI_INT] = sizeof(int);`. There may be also little-endian/big-endian conversions if your MPI implementation has to support heterogenous systems. In fact, implementing MPI from scratch is a rather complex task (e.g. do you know how to implement MPI_Barrier()?). I'd advise to take an existing implementation and adapt it to your system.